# Reading "data-id" attribute with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to use the nice plugin called [jRating](http://demos.myjqueryplugins.com/jrating/) , which supposedly does some kind of AJAX call when I click on the stars. It does it, with the right rate value, but the `data-id` attribute, which will be an input to the MySQL query in the AJAX-called file, is undefined (NaN). This is the code:

**Demo HTML**:

```
<div class="exemple"> 
   <!-- in this exemple, 12 is the average and 1 is the id of the line to update in DB -->
   <div class="basic" data-average="12" data-id="1"></div> 
</div>
```

**[jRating.jquery.js](http://demos.myjqueryplugins.com/jrating/jquery/jRating.jquery.js)**:

```
//Line 60:
//idBox = parseInt($(this).attr('data-id')), // old version, idBox=Nan
idBox = parseInt($(this).data("id")); // my version, still idBox=Nan
```

**edit**:
the jquery call in the main php page's header:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".exemple").jRating({
      length:10,
      decimalLength:0,
      onSuccess : function(){
        alert('Success : your rate has been saved :)');
      },
      onError : function(){
        alert('Error : please retry');
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

I can't seem to figure out what's wrong. Please help me to find it.
Thanks !

**SOLUTION** :

As @ZachL recognized,
`$(this)` , in jRating.jquery.js was referring to div.exemple, whereas the data-id was in div.basic.

So changing `$(this).data("id")` to `$(this).find('.basic').data("id")` worked.

Comment: I imagine its a problem with `$(this)`. What do you get when you log that out?

Comment: Is `this` points to `div.basic` or `div.exemple` or something else ?

Comment: I agree with Zach.  `$(this)` is probably not the element you think it is, because `$(this).data("id")` should work.

Comment: @ZachL that sounds right, but there is a piece of code that makes me think $(this) is div.exemple. that is 6 lines above idBox in the jrating.js file i provided. I'm really stuck here.. Thanks for all comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the script is looking for the data attribute on `<div class="exemple">`, but it only exists on `<div class="basic">`.

You can try `idBox = parseInt($(this).find('.basic').data("id"));`

Comment: Yes, that worked ! I wonder how does the code work (or does it) in their demo page. Thanks everybody, for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your problem is not `$(this)`, use `$(this).data("id")` to get the `data-id` attribute. Make sure you are using jQuery 1.6 or newer.

Comment: He tried `$(this).attr('data-id')`, and moreover, it is not the preferred method of retrieving data attributes. jQuery's `.data()` method is.

Comment: Try changing `$(this).data("id")` to `$('.basic').data('id');` to check if `$(this)` is the problem.